# Translate Bitvise settings to SSH Commands

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding

Is there any way I can display the ssh commands that bitvise is actualy using?

In detail:

I have a configuration made by the previous developer that I would like to adapt to my .ssh/config file.

So in bitvise I have 2 profiles:

Profile A has the following settings:

- login:

  - host: server_a
  - port: 22
  - username: my_server_a_user
  - initial method: publickey - slot 1
- C2S:

  - Status: enabled
  - Listen Interface: 127.0.0.1
  - list. port: 23
  - destination host: server_b
  - dest. port: 22

Profile B has the following settings:

- login:

  - host: 127.0.0.1
  - port: 23
  - username: my_server_b_user
  - initial method: publickey - slot 1
- C2S:

  - Status: enabled
  - Listen Interface: 127.0.0.1
  - list. port: 24
  - destination host: server_c
  - dest. port: 22

With this configuration I can login into 2 seperate servers using:

- my_server_b_user@127.0.0.1:23

and

- my_server_b_user@127.0.0.1:24

Can anyone help me translate these settings into commands/entries that I can put into the ssh config file?

Also any suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Bitvise Tunnelier *isn't* using any ssh commands. It's a full SSH client by itself, and does not run OpenSSH nor PuTTY under the hood.

A similar OpenSSH configuration would be:

```
ssh -i my_key.pub -L 23:server_b:22 -L 24:server_c:22 my_server_a_user@server_a
```

equivalent to:

```
Host server_a
    User my_server_a_user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_key.pub
    LocalForward 23:server_b:22
    LocalForward 24:server_c:22
```

To connect over the tunnels, use:

```
ssh -p 23 my_server_b_user@localhost
ssh -p 24 my_server_c_user@localhost
```

---

That said, in OpenSSH you can use a different, more direct approach:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p my_server_a_user@server_a" my_server_b_user@server_b
```

equivalent to:

```
Host server_a
    User my_server_a_user

Host server_b
    User my_server_b_user
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p server_a

Host server_c
    User my_server_c_user
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p server_a
```

*This* configuration lets you connect via the tunnel by simply running `ssh server_c`.

Comment: Hmm can you elaborate on the direct approach? For example I cannot conenct directly to server_b without going through server_a and the same for server_c which needs to go through b. After reading the man page on ssh_config i know that ProxyCommand runs whatever we sent it to the server right?  but in the config you provided you don't mention at any point a HostName.